# How to install net speed indicator on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: internet, 20.04, snap

I got nothing on Ubuntu snap store by searching "Simple net speed". 
So, suggest me a speed indicator for 20.04 and how to install it.

Comment: Did you try [`speedtest-cli`](https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli)? Or do you mean something like `iptraf`?

Comment: No. I didn't try anything

Comment: "best" is a matter of opinion so is going to be closed as such. In case you want an answer to this the question needs to have a lot more detail. Like a list of features and why specific tools that are already available are not good enough.  The generic command line tools are ping, netstat, traceroute. All are in the store by the way :)

Comment: Ok. I edited my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install the `Vitals` GNOME Shell extension, found [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1460/vitals/).

A glimpse into your computer's temperature, voltage, fan speed, memory usage, processor load, system resources, network speed and storage stats. This is a one stop shop to monitor all of your vital sensors. Uses asynchronous polling to provide a smooth user experience.

Comment: This extension is awesome. It contains features of both NetSpeed and `gnome-shell-extension-system-monitor`, saving my space in my top bar.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily do this with a gnome-shell-extension named NetSpeed.

## How to Install

To install NetSpeed you have to do the following:

### 1. Download the sources

First download the sources from [GitHub](https://github.com/hedayaty/NetSpeed). You can download via a browser or clone with git by:

```bsh
git clone https://github.com/hedayaty/NetSpeed.git
```

### 2. Unpack the sources

If you downloaded via terminal with git then you don't need follow this step.

Unpack it using archive manager or via terminal with:

```bsh
tar xf <downloaded-file>
```

### 3. Install it

If you downloaded with git then just issue this command on terminal:

```bsh
cd NetSpeed
```

If you downloaded with browser, then open the directory which you extracted the sources and right click. Select "Open in Terminal". A terminal window will open.

Now whatever method you used download to you have to execute these commands on terminal:

```bsh
make install
make enable
```

Now you should see NetSpeed  at the upper-right corner of your screen. If not press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and type "r" (without quotes) in the popup textbox and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Now you should see it and manage it at Extensions app.